# Linear Regression with repeated measurements of replicate samples?

Tags: regression, repeated-measures

This is a simple question but I has bugged me for some time. Can someone please share a link, or describe, how I can perform a linear regression from repeated measures of replicate samples over a range. The picture represents the average of each of these replicates.
I would prefer to use Matlab if you have any ideas that would fit with the problem.
Thanks
[image: Linear Regression with repeated measurements]

Comment: I don't follow the "over a range" part, & I'm not sure how to interpret the figure. If you are just wondering about repeated measures regression, it's to use a mixed-effects model.

Comment: You appear to have repeated y values at your x values. That's okay, just include them in the regression. Or is each point on the plot the average of other y values? Please explain.

Comment: #Tom Lane_Exactly, every point on the plot is an average of repeated measures from one sample. Do you have a link that could help me, or at the least some better terminology that will help me in my search?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you fit a GEE model if the purpose of the replication was simply to take care of errors in measurement rather than observe changes across replications. Otherwise, I would go for a [Mixed-effects model](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CDwQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pitt.edu%2F~super4%2F33011-34001%2F33151-33161.ppt&ei=KvsjVO6yEcjjaMSNgvAN&usg=AFQjCNEcvlAR1l1yvbb72_APOiSBM1ZFng&sig2=5XORpqJLm0CXvle0g6Cm-g).